# Duplicate name Viewport in React Native

Tags: react-native

The terminal where simulator is executed shows the following error:

```
Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
Duplicate module name: ViewportMetrics
Paths: /Users/fcojriosbello/Documents/Development/netbeast/node_modules/react/lib/ViewportMetrics.js collides with  /Users/fcojriosbello/Documents/Development/netbeast/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/node_modules/react-native-experimental-navigation/node_modules/react/lib/ViewportMetrics.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of npm do you have? You have a pairDependencies problem so try to get npm v3.

Anyway if you do:

```
rm -rf  /Users/fcojriosbello/Documents/Development/netbeast/node_modules/react-native-router-flux/node_modules/react-native-experimental-navigation/node_modules/react/
```

Should work